# Google Maps V3 air/sea transport?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

im trying to use the directionsService from GoogleMaps, and i have this types of transports

```
BICYCLING   Specifies a bicycling directions request.
DRIVING Specifies a driving directions request.
TRANSIT Specifies a transit directions request.
WALKING Specifies a walking directions request.
```

But i dont have Sea or Air types, it should be like a single line in the map.
I need to draw mixed routes with land types and air(sea
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Get the sea and air routes via another source.

Comment: Yes, i was tracing a polyline for this cases, but if i have a route with many segments and types, not worked well